# Datatable containing HTML string

Tags: html, winforms, datatable

In a Winforms application, I have a datatable in which one of its columns contain HTML string. I want to render the whole datatable contents on the form or in HTML where the inner HTML contents should also get rendered.

I am using C# to do this. The reason I want the HTML is that the datatable contains a report and the inner HTML contains links to images.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what language you're using but you'll need to HTML encode the HTML string from the datatable.  Most languages will contain a method for this that takes a string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to put HTML in a windows application? Do you have an HTML Editor?

With regards to web, the normal procedure would be to store the data, in a normal table, and when you load you place the HTML in a `<div>`. If you put `runat="server"` in the `div`, you can set the innerhtml attribute from the server side.